# Javascript not outputting left angle bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code which creates a 'typing text effect' on a page - i.e. javascript takes a string and outputs it on the screen in a way that makes it look like it is being typed. I took the code from a demo [here](http://rachstock.com/demos/typing-animation/).

The problem is that I want it to output html code, e.g. the output on the screen should be something like:

```
<html>
<body>
Something here etc etc...
</body>
</head>
```

In chrome, this works in a rather erratic fashion - sometimes it works perfectly, but other times it doesn't display the first left angle bracket, leaving me with the output of `'html>'` rather than `'<html>'`. In safari, the left angle bracket doesn't display at all. I've tried various things, using `'&lt;'` instead of the bracket, using unicode, but that everything I do seems to end with the same result.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/nmfraser/5983856) is a github gist of the code, and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/nmfraser/5983856) is a bl.ocks page to showing it in action. I tried to make a jsfiddle but couldn't get it to run properly, sorry!

Any help is much appreciated, it's been driving me nuts.
Cheers
Nick

Comment: Does the problem happen when viewing the bl.ocks page example? I've tried it about 10 times, and it's worked fine each time for me in Chrome v27.

Comment: The example page worked for me too (in Chrome).

Comment: @nnnnnn I guess I read it as him wanting to render them as HTML, not actually display the tags. My fault. I tested the demo bl.ocks example in IE10 and it worked.

Comment: Jason Evans - it works most (90%) of the time in Chrome. Occassionally it doesn't - I have no idea why, it's completely erratic. In the bl.ocks example, it seems to work fine. In safari (for me) it doesn't work at all.

Comment: _"I tried to make a jsfiddle but couldn't get it to run properly"_ - Here's a working JSFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/KH588/ (it's just a matter of copying the pieces into the right windows and selecting the required version of jQuery from the "Frameworks & Extensions" section on the left).

Comment: Thanks...not sure what I did wrong there then. The problem seems to have been solved by Abraham below. Thanks for all the fast replies.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$span.append(thisLine[letterIndex]);
```

try

```
$span.text($span.text() + thisLine[letterIndex]);
```

Or, per crush's comment below, you could do a string replace:

```
$span.append(thisLine[letterIndex].replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;'));
```

This works because when you want to display HTML tags, you need to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` rather than just `<` and `>`, otherwise the browser thinks you're putting in an actual HTML tag, if that makes sense to you. The jquery [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method automatically escapes the brackets for you, and in my second example, we're just doing a string replace before passing the string to `append`.

Comment: A better solution would be to escape `thisLine[letterIndex]` before appending it...

Comment: aha, this seems to work! Can you expand on why this works and the previous code didn't?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the code appends `'&lt;'` as '&','l','t',';'. Not verified this but you might want to try:

```
 function typeLetter(lineIndex, letterIndex, $span, line, callback) {
   var thisLine = line;
   var thisLength = line.length;
   var chunk='';

   // add the letter
   chunk=thisLine[letterIndex];
   if ('&'==thisLine[letterIndex]) {
        for (var i=1; i<5; i++) {
           letterIndex++;
           chunk+=thisLine[letterIndex];
           if (';'==thisLine[letterIndex] || letterIndex>=thisLength-1) break;
        }
   }
   $span.append(chunk);
   ...
```

Comment: Ah that is true since it is searching by character.